# Calculate time difference for records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have below table named `acttable1`.

```
NUMBER TYPE           DATESTAMP            DESCRIPTION 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10010  OPEN           2014-04-16 05:34:03  ASSIGNED TO GROUP 1
10010  REASSIGNMENT   2014-04-19 09:29:00  REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 1 TO GROUP 2
10010  REASSIGNMENT   2014-04-20 08:35:00  REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 2 TO GROUP 3
10010  CLOSED         2014-04-20 10:15:33  CLOSED
```

I need to calculate total time(time difference between every value in `DATESTAMP` column) ticket was with `GROUP 1`, `GROUP 2`, `GROUP 3`.

Please assist me in building a SQL query so that I can extract report.

Expected output.

```
NUMBER  TYPE          DATESTAMP         Duration    DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10010   OPEN          04/19/14 00:45    00:00:00    ASSIGNED TO GROUP 1
10010   REASSIGNMENT  04/19/14 09:29    08:44:00    REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 1 TO GROUP 2
10010   REASSIGNMENT  04/20/14 07:29    22:00:00    REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 2 TO GROUP 3
10010   CLOSED        04/20/14 10:15    02:46:33    CLOSED
```

I am using MS SQL 2008 Database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: Parsing the description to get the assigned group... that'll be ugly

Comment: by mistake i entered the same datestamp for 2 reassignments. It should have been 2014-04-19 09:29:00 and 2014-04-20 08:35:00.

Comment: it should be parsed based on type column not on description. Hence, we need to find out datestamp difference from type = open to 1st occurance of type=Reassignment then datestamp difference from 1st occurance of type = Reassignment  to 2nd occurance of type=Reassignment..so on.

Comment: NUMBER TYPE DATESTAMP Duration DESCRIPTION
10010 OPEN 04/19/14 00:45 00:00:00 ASSIGNED TO GROUP 1
10010 REASSIGNMENT 04/19/14 09:29 08:44:00 REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 1 TO GROUP 2
10010 REASSIGNMENT 04/20/14 07:29 22:00:00 REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 2 TO GROUP 3
10010 CLOSED 04/20/14 10:15 02:46:33 CLOSED

Comment: @user4473935 Can you include the expected output as an edit by clicking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28045703/edit)

Comment: Which version of sql server do you use?

Comment: your datestamp for your output doesn't match the tabledata

Comment: will the NUMBER be reused for new sets of data ? what does the number indicate ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    Number
    , Type
    , DateStamp
   , CAST(CAST(SECONDS/60/60%24 as VARCHAR) + ':'+ 
     CAST((SECONDS/60)%60 as VARCHAR) + ':' +
     CAST(SECONDS%60 as VARCHAR) AS TIME) AS TotalTime
    , Description
FROM
    (SELECT CurrentEvent.NUMBER
        ,CurrentEvent.TYPE
        ,CurrentEvent.DATESTAMP
        ,DATEDIFF(SECOND, CurrentEvent.DATESTAMP, ISNULL(NextEvent.DATESTAMP, CurrentEvent.DateStamp)) AS SECONDS
        ,CurrentEvent.DESCRIPTION
    FROM (
        SELECT NUMBER
            ,TYPE
            ,DATESTAMP
            ,DESCRIPTION
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER ORDER BY DATESTAMP) Ordering
        FROM acttable1
        ) AS CurrentEvent LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT NUMBER
            ,DATESTAMP
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER ORDER BY DATESTAMP) Ordering
        FROM acttable1
        ) AS NextEvent ON CurrentEvent.Ordering + 1 = NextEvent.Ordering
    ) AS FinalResultSet
```

The basic idea would be to order the results based on their `DATESTAMP` and then use a `LEFT JOIN` to bring two consecutive rows on the same row and then be able to subtract the time difference between the two dates.

After this just formatting is done with the help of the last query, after the duration in seconds between two consecutive events has been calculated.

Comment: it seems some issue with above script. I am unable to compile / run it. 1st 5 lines are showing errors. My actual table name is ACTPROBM1. This table does not contain any column like Duration. We need calculate the time duration dynamically and show it as an alias column.

Comment: @user4473935 Try again, I modified the query. I noticed the additional `Duration` column and removed it. Use the current query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace @t with your tablename and try this:

Test table and data:

```
DECLARE @t table
(NUMBER int, TYPE varchar(20), DATESTAMP datetime, DESCRIPTION varchar(40))
INSERT @t values
(10010,'OPEN','2014-04-16 05:34:03','ASSIGNED TO GROUP 1'),
(10010,'REASSIGNMENT','2014-04-19 09:28:00','REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 1 TO GROUP 2'),
(10010,'REASSIGNMENT','2014-04-20 08:35:00','REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 2 TO GROUP 3'),
(10010,'CLOSED','2014-04-20 10:15:33','CLOSED')
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  NUMBER, 
  TYPE,
  DATESTAMP, 
  datestamp - (SELECT max(DATESTAMP) FROM @t 
              WHERE datestamp < t.datestamp and 
              number = t.number) AS Duration, 
  DESCRIPTION
FROM @t t
```

Result:

```
NUMBER TYPE           DATESTAMP           Duration            DESCRIPTION
10010  OPEN           2014-04-16 05:34:03                     ASSIGNED TO GROUP 1
10010  REASSIGNMENT   2014-04-19 09:28:00 1900-01-04 03:53:57 REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 1 TO GROUP 2
10010  REASSIGNMENT   2014-04-20 08:35:00 1900-01-01 23:07:00 REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 2 TO GROUP 3
10010  CLOSED         2014-04-20 10:15:33 1900-01-01 01:40:33 CLOSED
```

If you prefer, you can convert duration as time:

```
cast( datestamp - (SELECT max(DATESTAMP) FROM @t 
              WHERE datestamp < t.datestamp and 
              number = t.number) as time)
```

Comment: The script will fail if the same combination of Number and type repeat in future.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti yes it would, but i expect the number describe the group it belong to. Meaning the group would never repeat. Type has nothing to do with my script

Answer (score 0):

The below script gets you what you want.

```
select *, case when type = 'CLOSED' THEN 3 WHEN type = 'REASSIGNMENT' then 2 WHEN TYPE = 'OPEN' THEN 1 END AS Num 
into #acttable1
from acttable1

create table #abc
(
id int identity(1,1)
,number int
,type varchar(20)
,datestamp datetime
,description varchar(100)
)
--drop table #abc 
insert into #abc
select number, type, datestamp, description from #acttable1 order by Num, datestamp

select A.*, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ISNULL(datediff(ss, B.datestamp, A.datestamp), 0)/3600) 
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(ISNULL(datediff(ss, B.datestamp, A.datestamp), 0)%3600)/60),2) 
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),ISNULL(datediff(ss, B.datestamp, A.datestamp), 0)%60),2) AS [Duration] 
from #abc A left join #abc B on A.id - 1 = B.id
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7710/3)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite close but something like this should work

**SCHEMA**:

```
CREATE TABLE acttable1
(
    [NUMBER] int not null,
    [TYPE] varchar(25) not null,
    [DATESTAMP] datetime not null,
    [DESCRIPTION] varchar(255) not null
);

INSERT INTO acttable1 
    ([NUMBER], [TYPE], [DATESTAMP], [DESCRIPTION])
VALUES
    (10010, 'OPEN', '2014-04-19 00:45.000', 'ASSIGNED TO GROUP 1'),
    (10010, 'REASSIGNMENT', '2014-04-19 09:29:00.000',  'REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 1 TO GROUP 2'),
    (10010, 'REASSIGNMENT', '2014-04-20 07:29:00.000', 'REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 2 TO GROUP 3'),
    (10010, 'CLOSED', '2014-04-20 10:15:33.000', 'CLOSED');
```

**SQL QUERY**:

```
;WITH cteAssignments
AS
(
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [NUMBER] ORDER BY [DATESTAMP]) AS SeqNo,
          [NUMBER], 
          [TYPE], 
          [DATESTAMP], 
          [DESCRIPTION]
  FROM    acttable1    
)

SELECT 
      a1.*,
      COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEDIFF(s, a2.[DATESTAMP], a1.[DATESTAMP])/3600) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEDIFF(s, a2.[DATESTAMP], a1.[DATESTAMP]) % 3600/60) +':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (DATEDIFF(s, a2.[DATESTAMP], a1.[DATESTAMP]) % 60)), '00:00:00') as Duration    
FROM cteAssignments a1
LEFT JOIN    cteAssignments a2
  ON a2.SeqNo + 1 = a1.SeqNo
```

will produce the following results:

```
SEQNO   NUMBER  TYPE              DATESTAMP                     DESCRIPTION                             DURATION
    1   10010   OPEN              April, 19 2014 00:45:00+0000  ASSIGNED TO GROUP 1                     00:00:00
    2   10010   REASSIGNMENT      April, 19 2014 09:29:00+0000  REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 1 TO GROUP 2    8:44:0
    3   10010   REASSIGNMENT      April, 20 2014 07:29:00+0000  REASSIGNMENT FROM GROUP 2 TO GROUP 3    22:0:0
    4   10010   CLOSED            April, 20 2014 10:15:33+0000  CLOSED                                  2:46:33
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13fc30/1)**